# How can I troubleshoot Chromium connectivity to website?

Tags: oracle, ssl, tomcat, oracle-apex, chromium

We have a public website developed using Oracle APEX which uses Tomcat. The site runs on a Windows 2016 server and is behind a wildacrd ssl. A few users reported Chromium browsers (Chrome & Edge) were having a problem connecting to the site. The error displayed is "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

When run from IE of Firefox the site works fine. Many Chromium browsers also work fine. We discovered internally some of our Chrome & Edge browser work, and some don't.

Troubleshooting steps we've taken so far include;

1. F12 on chrome. The error which displays is "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." When searching for these issues the only thing found is a reference to launch.json which seems .NET related and this is a Tomcat application.
2. Run Fiddler. When enabling Fiddler on the client using Fiddler's builtin proxy the site works fine.
3. Try different SSL certificate. We have tried two different wildcard SSLs neither work. We tried single SSL and the Chrome/Edge browsers which didn't work, started working.
4. Run SSL diagnostic tools. Everything tried thus far show the SSL to be in good shape. With only TLS 1.2 allowed.
5. Verified versions of browsers and OSes which work & don't work. Found no pattern.
6. Ran cleanup on Chrome.
7. Tried a computer with a non-working browser on different networks.

At this point we do not what to try next. Which is why I am asking for help here.

I will update this question as we try additional steps.

Comment: can you share the tomcat logs?

Comment: take a look of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638710/tls-setting-in-chrome-vs-ie-err-connection-reset

Comment: I am not using client certificates, and I checked the browser on one of the computers which does not work and it has TLS 1.2 checked.

Comment: Does your server have last patch applied?

Comment: The server is 2019 completely up to date.

Comment: Are you behind a VPN or something? Try to review your proxy settings

Comment: reset the Winsock catalog in CMD as Administrator run c:\netsh winsock reset

Comment: https://appuals.com/best-fix-err_connection_reset/

Comment: The problem is occurring from multiple locations. The server behind a firewall, however different computers at the same remote location behave differently. Some work & some don't.

Comment: Looks like you have a client issue. Same OS? what is different?

Comment: All of the clients tried are various versions of Windows. I have gone so far as making sure the OS on two computers behaving differently are identical Windows 10 - 21H2 with all updates. The version of Chrome & Edge appear to be the same as well.